# In python flask how to allow a user to re-arrange list items and record in database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have a flask sqlalchemy bootsrap app.
My template renders a list of items in a table that I would like the user to be able to rearrange.  The items get displayed through standard jinja2

```
 {% for item in List %}
 {{item}}
  {%end for%}
```

so how can i allow the user to rearrange the order of the objects and then record those changes?

One idea i had was  to get [jquery sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#placeholder) to allow re-arranging and then send the new values to my database (either upon submit, or as they are re-arranged).

But, how do i write a sqlalchemy statement to update the appropriate row in my database?  What is the piece between javascript and python where I identify which row in the db to change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery UI's [`sortable`](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) has a `toArray` message - when it is called on a sortable it returns the IDs of the elements in the order they appear in the DOM.  This is probably the simplest way to handle things:

```
<ul id="theSortableStuff">
{% for item in things_to_sort %}
    <li id="item-{{ item.id }}">{{ item.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<script>
var $sortables = $("#theSortableStuff").sortable({
  stop: function() {
    var sortedItems = $sortables.sortable("toArray");
    // Update some form in the DOM or use AJAX to invoke a server-side update
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Javascript newbies (like me) might find this link to info about the javascript document object model (DOM) useful - https://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_htmldom.asp